# How to replace a string of which you only know the start and the end?

Tags: php, regex, string

I've got a string in php in which I've got a tag:

```
$str = "bla bla {video something} bla bla";
```

in which `something` can be literally anything.

I now want to replace `{video something}` with `<iframe id=123>`. I guess I need a regex for this, but I'm kinda lost in the whole regex thing. Does anybody know how I can do this?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: May be use this regex: `/{video\h+[^}]+}/` or `preg_replace('/{video\h+[^}]+}/',  '<iframe id=123>', $str);`

Comment: `(?<=bla bla ).+?(?=bla bla)` - https://regex101.com/r/QWbU8T/1

Comment: Can you provide us with more information, maybe some more sample strings? Also what *exactly* is "*known*" as you proclaim but fail to specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace everything between curly braces in your provided string which begins with video, you could use:

[`{(?=video.*?})(.*?)}`](https://regex101.com/r/Sh3QUO/1)

**Explanation**

- Match an opening curly brace `{`
- A positive lookahead `(?=video.*?})` which asserts that what follows is video till a closing brace
- Capture in a group any character non greedy `(.*?)`
- Match a closing brace `}`

For example:

```
$string = "bla bla {video something} bla bla";
$string = preg_replace ('/{(?=video.*?})(.*?)}/',"<iframe id=123>", $string);
echo $string;
```

[Output](https://3v4l.org/70eoh)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$str = "bla bla {video something} bla bla";
$str=preg_replace ('/{(.*?)}/',"<iframe id=123>",$str);
echo $str;
```

This code will look for the curly braces and replace them + everything in them with your iframe